# class.phpmailer.php returns SMTP connect() failed error in 000webhost.com

Tags: php, email

I use `class.phpmailer.php` to send a confirmation email. It works perfectly in my local server, but when I upload it to the server in `000webhost.com` it no longer works.
I just discovered `mail()` is not working anymore either.
Is there something I can do to solve this?
Here is the code of the function I use to send every mail in my system:
`code`

```
function correoEnviar($asunto, $mensaje, $mensajeTexto, $email)
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';  // Specify main and backup server
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'xxxx@yahoo.com.mx';                            // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

    $mail->From = 'xxxx@yahoo.com.mx';
    $mail->FromName = 'xxxx';
    $mail->addAddress($email);               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('xxxx@yahoo.com.mx', 'Information');

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    //$mail->Subject = 'Por favor confirme su correo para obtener el libro El fractal y el =?UTF-8?Q?dise=C3=B1o=C2=A0gr=C3=A1fico?=';
    $mail->Subject = $asunto;
    $mail->Body    = $mensaje;
    $mail->AltBody = $mensajeTexto;

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        return $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
        return 1;
}

echo correoEnviar($asunto, $mensaje, $mensajeTexto, "recipent@gmail.com");
```

?>
`code`

Comment: And what error shows?

Comment: The error it returns is SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: Of course I included the classes. It works perfectly in my house, but it doesn't in the real server. Could it be a bad PHP config?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are including the file class.phpmailer.php, your code seems fine.

Paste the server's mailserver log, it will provide a better insight.

Your code is fine, it might be a server issue.

A sample code showing SMTP settings

```
require ("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn of SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "YAHOO ACCOUNT";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "YAHOO ACCOUNT PASSWORD"; // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "YAHOO HOST"; // SMTP host
$mail->Port = 465;
```